# Creating forms with method="get" in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form containing two text input types. The value from both the forms are passed onto the view `myfunc` which then passes it on to another template.the url of the form results should be

`/app/1/new_page/?key=key&value=value`

But on submitting the form, it goes to the following url -

```
/app/1/new_page/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=CpYebRXTmLkHfo6hRQSrfZPdMFjWW9Ri&key=a1&value=41325
```

and gives the error -

```
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    <WSGIRequest: GET '/app/1/new_page/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=CpYebRXTmLkHfo6hRQSrfZPdMFjWW9Rikey=a1&value=41325'>
```

Even manually entering the correct url gives the same `Exception Type and Value`

But I have declared the template in the view. What could be the problem here?

`template containing form`

```
<form action="{% url 'my_func' id %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="key" type="text" name="key" value="">
    <input id="value" type="text" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`views.py`

```
def myfunc(request, id):
    key = request.GET.get('key')
    value = request.GET.get('value')
    context = {'key': key}
    return render_to_response(request,'template.html', context)
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^app/(?P<id>\d+)/new-page/$', views.myfunc, name="my_func"),
```

Comment: `TemplateDoesNotExist`, you are missing file `template.html`.

Comment: No the file is there. Because another view is accessing the same template. The error is `TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/1/new_page/` The traceback doesn't even mention the template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with forms or GET.

You have used the `render_to_response` shortcut, which takes two positional arguments: template and context. But you have passed three arguments, putting the request first; that shortcut does not take the request.

I think you meant to just use the `render` shortcut, which *does* take the request first.

```
return render(request,'template.html', context)
```

Comment: Why is the `csrfmiddlewaretoken=CpYebRXTmLkHfo6hRQSrfZPdMFjWW9Ri&` part appended to the url? Is it because of the `csrf` token?

Comment: Yes; it's in the form, so gets submitted along with the rest of the data. You don't need it for a GET submission though, you can omit the tag completely.